# VB.NET Generic list type filter: How to do it?

Tags: vb.net, generics, .net-4.0, filter, type-conversion

I would like to write a generic function that would search a List(Of T) for all elements of type TFilter and return a List(Of TFilter) which comprises those elements.  I've tried this:

```
Public Function FilterList(Of T, TFilter)(ByVal ListToFilter As List(Of T)) As List(Of TFilter)
    Return ListToFilter.FindAll(Function(z) z.GetType.Equals(GetType(TFilter))).ConvertAll(New Converter(Of T, TFilter)(Function(z) CType(z, TFilter)))
End Function
```

But, it gives the following error:

> Value of type 'T' cannot be converted
>   to 'TFilter'.

Is there any way to do this or am I SOL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should happen to values that inherit `TFilter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to constrain `TFilter` to inherit `T`:

```
Public Function FilterList(Of T, TFilter As T)(...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to write any code for this. You can just call

```
listToFilter.OfType(Of TFilter).ToList()
```

See the docs for [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) for more details.

(I'm assuming you are using .NET 3.5 or higher.)

Comment: Oooh...  I was unaware.  Thanks for the tip!